# Text moves more to the right when looping

Tags: script, powershell

This is my output below when creating a function with a for loop inside it:

```
NO      Type
--      ----

 1       System.Int32 
 2       System.Int32 
 3       System.Int32 
 4       System.Int32 
 5       System.Int32 
 6       System.Int32 
 7       System.Int32 
 8       System.Int32 
 9       System.Int32 
 10          System.Int32
```

You see that when 10 comes, it moves the System.Int32 more to the right. How do I change that inside my code? This is probably not related to only Powershell.

**Code:**

```
function CountTen() {
    [array]$ListOfNumbers = @()
    [array]$NumbersType = @()

    for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
        $ListOfNumbers += ("`n", $i, "`t`t", ($i.GetType()))
    }

    Write-Host "NO`t`tType"
    Write-Host "--`t`t----"
    Write-Host $ListOfNumbers, "`t`t", $NumbersType
}

CountTen
```

Comment: Because you are outputting tabs. When you reach `10` the extra digit forces the next tab  stop to be further to the right.

Comment: How can I do this different then?

Comment: <shrug> If the number has two digits output 1 tab instead of 2 tabs? It's your code, you need to decide what is acceptable.

Comment: What @DavidPostill said. What is the purpose of this script? Just printing numbers isn't often very useful, except if you are just getting started at all in programming (which, don't get me wrong on this, is perfectly valid!). If you tell us what problem you are trying to solve by writing this script, or what your ultimate goal is (please [edit] your post to do so; do not respond in comments) then we can perhaps suggest a better solution. This looks much like [an X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/157730).

Answer (score 0):

You should check formatting  (-f) of PS. A sample can be found here: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_-f_format.htm

So, for advanced formatting, the following pattern can be used:
*format* **-f** *values*
like

```
"text {x,xlength} text {y,ylength} text" -f xvalue, yvalue
```

where x (and y) are the position of the value listed behind -f. That value must appear in the text where {...} is placed. xlength (and ylength) is the width with which the appropriate value will be displayed. Lengths are optional.

The current problem can be redefined this way using specific formatting:

```
function CountTen() {
    $format = "{0,5} {1}"
    [array]$ListOfNumbers = @()
    [array]$NumbersType = @()

    $format -f "NO", "Type"
    $format -f "--", "----"

    for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) {
        $format -f $i, $i.GetType()       
    }
}

CountTen
```

Here the integers and their header is aligned "flush right" (as figures often are) in a 5 character long field.

Comment: Given that the OP seems to be a beginner at powershell you should think about providing an example that actually solves his problem instead of just a link.

Comment: I do respect your comment and I would gladly give examples but I would not do that (never do) without trying everything out but I do not have Win at hand. I will be back when trying is possible to check if Zrg  is till fighting this issue our the induction worked.